# Regroup by day, then regroup again by the hour

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dictionary list of items.  For example

```
activities = [
{'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 8, 0), 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 9, 0), 
 u'name': u'First Activity', 'description': 'desc of first activity...'}, 
{'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 9, 0), 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 10, 0), 
 u'name': u'Second Activity', 'description': 'desc of next activity...'}, 
{'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 22, 8, 0), 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 9, 0), 
 u'name': u'Third Activity', 'description': 'desc of third activity...'}, 
{'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 8, 0), 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 9, 0), 
 u'name': u'Next Activity', 'description': 'desc of next activity...'}, 
{'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 9, 0), 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 10, 0), 
 u'name': u'Another Activity', 'description': 'desc of another activity...'}, 
{'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 10, 0), 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 11, 0), 
 u'name': u'New Activity', 'description': 'desc of new activity...'}
]
```

I would like to do a regroup, first by the day, then perform a second regroup by the hour.

I'm having trouble enough just getting a regroup to work by either the day or by hour.

For example:

```
{% regroup activities by start|date:"l, n/d" as activity_list_by_day %}
    {% for session in activity_list_by_day %}
        {{ session.grouper }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Isn't working out well. I don't see how to specify that I want the regroup to work by the day.

Is there some way to manipulate my 'start' item for these regroupings?  Or might I need to create some extra items to work with?

---

Edited to add: I see now I can start out by sorting my activities list with:

```
activities.sort(key=lambda item:item['start'])
```

This helps tremendously.  Actually might have solved my own problem...